# How is $\lambda_j(0) = N^{-1}$ for Lagrange polynomials in the Baloo paper's generalized sumcheck?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I'm reading inner product from generalized sumcheck in baloo paper (P.13), I'm confused with $\lambda_j(0) = N^{-1}$. Can anyone shed some light?

Here's excerpt from the paper

> The intuition is that for all Lagrange interpolation polynomials $\{\lambda_j(X)\}_{j=1}^{N}$ corresponding to a multiplicative subgroup H of size N, we have $\lambda_j(0) = N^{-1}$

My understanding is that Lagrange polynomials at zero would not necessarily yield $N^{-1}$, unless specifically normalized to do so, especially since they are constructed to be $1$ at their corresponding point in the subgroup and $0$ at all others.

Reference:
baloo: https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/1565.pdf (see page 13 for the relevant section).

Comment: Please use mathjax and edit equations properly

Comment: @kodlu thank you, I've modified the format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the paper (section 3.1) the polynomials $\lambda_j(X)$ specifically refer to the Lagrange basis polynomials at the $N$th roots of unity which are 0 at exactly one of the roots and zero at the others, which normalises them.

Specifically, we have
$$\lambda_j(X):=\prod_{i\neq j}\frac{X-\omega_i}{\omega_j-\omega_i}.$$
Now recall that $\prod_i\omega_i=(-1)^{N+1}$, so that $\prod_{i\neq j}(-\omega_i)=\omega_j^{-1}$. Recall further that
$$\prod_{i\neq 0}(X-\omega_i)=\frac{(X^N-1)}{(X-1)}=1+X+\cdots+X^{N-1}.$$

Now
\begin{eqnarray}\lambda_j(0)&=&\frac{\prod_{i\neq j}(-\omega_i)}{\prod_{i\neq j}(\omega_j-\omega_i)}\\
&=&\frac{\omega_j^{-1}}{\omega_j^{-1}\prod_{i\neq j}(1-\omega_{i-j})}\\
&=&\frac1{\prod_{i'\neq 0}(1-\omega_{i'})}\\
&=&\frac1{1+1+1^2+\cdots+1^{N-1}}\\
&=&\frac1N
\end{eqnarray}